# You need to select at least one radio button / checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, dom

What would be the JavaScript code to check if the user has selected at least one radio button, knowing that the radio buttons all have the same "name" attribute?

Same question for checkboxes.

I do not use any fancy javascript frameworks such as JQuery and others ...

Comment: "I do not use any fancy javascript frameworks such as JQuery and others ...".  Well, maybe you should.

Comment: I would agree with SLaks. I would start by familiarizing myself with jQuery (or something similar) if I want to do anything dynamic apart from, say, alert('hello world!');

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682964/in-javascript-how-can-i-get-all-radio-buttons-in-the-page-with-a-given-name

Comment: Will jquery work for anyone? (that has javascript enabled of course)

Comment: No point is picking up a chunky library to do one trivial thing.

Comment: @nute: Yes.  jQuery will work on any browser, and is more likely to work on obscure browsers than hand-written code.  (They devote lots of time to testing)

Comment: Agreed, a proper JS library will help iron out all of the cross-browser awfulness of inconsistent DOM implementations, etc.

Comment: Thanks - I am now using jQuery

Answer (score 1):

```
function IsARadioButtonChecked ( radiogroup ) {
    for (var i = 0; i < radiogroup.length; i++) {
        if (radiogroup[i].checked) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

if (IsARadioButtonChecked(document.forms.myForm.elements.myRadioGroupName)) {
    // …
}
```