# Passing a form value to a JavaScript Function

Tags: javascript

I have read through lots of postings here and around the net, and I even have books covering this subjective, but I just can't get it to work. I just can't get the Function to pick up the value of the "RadioDrink" variable. I have tried all sorts of combinations Using DOM methods like below and here using a collection (this) and (form) with no luck.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
function ValDrink(form){
if (form.RadioDrink.value == "soup")
    {
    alert("Its soup OK!");
    return true; // OK
     }
```

======================here is my code.======================

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>

<script type="text/JavaScript">
<!--
function ValDrink()
{   
    if (document.forms.Drinks.RadioDrink.value == "soup")
    {
      alert("Its soup OK!");
      return true; // soup
    }
    else
    {
      alert("OK");
      return false; // not soup
    }
}
//-->
</script>

</head>

<body>
  <form method="post" id="Drinks" name="Drinks" onsubmit="return ValDrink()">
    <input type="radio" checked name="RadioDrink" value="Tea">Tea<br>
    <input type="radio" name="RadioDrink" value="Coffee">Coffee<br>
    <input type="radio" name="RadioDrink" value="Soup">Soup<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="CheckMilk" value="Yes">Milk
    <input type="checkbox" name="CheckSugar" value="Yes">Sugar
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="OKButton" value="Vend">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check for each value in the radio group & use it instead. Something like :

```
function getCheckedRadio(radio_group) {
    for (var i = 0; i < radio_group.length; i++) {
        var button = radio_group[i];
        if (button.checked) {
            return button;
        }
    }
    return undefined;
}
```

Call it to get selected value. So In your case :

```
getCheckedRadio(document.forms.Drinks.RadioDrink);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give the value of "Soup" checkbox:

```
document.forms["Drinks"]["RadioDrink"][0].checked
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to do this in a different way. first of all your DOM is showing undefined value. you can add different ids to the radio buttons. you can do it like below

```
    <html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>

<script type="text/JavaScript">
<!--
function ValDrink()
{   
    if (document.getElementById("Rsoup").checked == true)
    {
    alert("its soup");
    return true; // soup
    }
    else
    {
    alert("its not soup");
    return false; // not soup
    }
}
//-->
</script>

</head>

<body>
<form method="post" id="Drinks" name="Drinks" onsubmit="return ValDrink()">
<input type="radio" checked name="RadioDrink" value="Tea">Tea<br>
<input type="radio" name="RadioDrink" value="Coffee">Coffee<br>
<input type="radio" name="RadioDrink" id="Rsoup" value="Soup">Soup<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="CheckMilk" value="Yes">Milk
<input type="checkbox" name="CheckSugar" value="Yes">Sugar
<br>
<input type="submit" name="OKButton" value="Vend">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that this:

```
document.forms.Drinks.RadioDrink
```

returns an array-like reference to all three inputs with that name, it doesn't return a reference to the currently selected one. So you can't just test the `value` property.

The easiest to explain way to achieve what you want to do is to give the radio buttons unique ids:

```
<input type="radio" checked name="RadioDrink" id="RadioDrinkTea" value="Tea">Tea<br>
<input type="radio" name="RadioDrink" id="RadioDrinkCoffee" value="Coffee">Coffee<br>
<input type="radio" name="RadioDrink" id="RadioDrinkSoup" value="Soup">Soup<br>
```

And then directly select the one you want to test:

```
if (document.getElementById("RadioDrinkSoup").checked) {
    alert("It's soup OK!");
    return true; // soup
} else {
    alert("OK");
    return false; // not soup
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try your coding like below... it will help you.....

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>

<script type="text/JavaScript">
<!--
function ValDrink() {
    var radios = document.getElementsByName('RadioDrink');
    var radioName;

    for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
        if (radios[i].checked) {
            radioName = radios[i].value;
        }
    }
    if (radioName.toUpperCase() == "soup".toUpperCase())
    {
    alert("Its soup OK!");
    return true; // soup
    }
    else
    {
    alert("OK");
    return false; // not soup
    }
}
//-->
</script>

</head>

<body>
<form method="post" id="Drinks" name="Drinks" onsubmit="return ValDrink()">
<input type="radio" checked name="RadioDrink" value="Tea">Tea<br>
<input type="radio" name="RadioDrink" value="Coffee">Coffee<br>
<input type="radio" name="RadioDrink" value="Soup">Soup<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="CheckMilk" value="Yes">Milk
<input type="checkbox" name="CheckSugar" value="Yes">Sugar
<br>
<input type="submit" name="OKButton" value="Vend">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a right way to get radios value. Use the following function, also can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1682964/1823389)

```
function ValDrink()
{   
    var radios =document.forms.Drinks.RadioDrink;

    for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
        if (radios[i].checked && radios[i].value==="Soup") {
            alert("Its soup OK!"); // soup
            return true;
        }
    }
    alert("OK");
    return false; // not soup
}
```